# What was the first piece of wood to reach the far side of the Moon? Or the first spacecraft?

Tags: the-moon, chang-e, spaceflight-firsts

Chang'e-4 is the first lander/rover mission to reach the far side, but probably doesn't have any wood on it.

What was the first piece of wood that landed on the far side of the Moon, and what was the first spacecraft to reach the surface of the far side?

Comment: don't know the answer, so down vote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it appears that either you already know the answer or this is a random question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble there's no rule against asking an occasional question to which you know the answer, none at all that I'm aware of. There's nothing wrong with asking a question in order to post your own answer either. The focus should generally be on good answers. Nonetheless I'll slightly de-emphasize the wood aspect...

Comment: @OrganicMarble Our rich heritage of wooden questions includes [Could a spacecraft be made out of wood?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21038/12102) and [Why is there a large wooden ball on Mariner 3's magnetometer?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20135/12102) and [White papers on alleged 1960s Chinese wooden ablative reentry heat shield](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21442/12102) and [Puzzler - which spacecraft(s) incorporated real wooden structural elements?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18856/12102)

Comment: Again, I wasn't the downvoter. I understand posting questions you know the answer to *and then answering them*; posting questions you know the answer to and not answering them seems like a waste of time.

Comment: @OrganicMarble okay. Either way all the n-1 other future readers benefit the same from the answer and the answer gets added to the accumulated knowledge here, but okay.

Comment: So write the answer already so future readers can benefit.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I wouldn't want to take the fun away from anyone. Let's let it go around the planet once or twice and see what happens.

Comment: @uhoh Feel free to provide a sourced answer, please.

Comment: @Polygnome until such time as I can do that, I'll delete this to avoid further down-voting

Comment: @Polygnome FOUND IT! Answering now...

Comment: ...or at least *postpone* the downvoting ;-)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DLNI.png

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't seem notable in any way. Usages of wood in space are valid questions, but asking about [material] in [location] for no apparent reason is not.

Comment: I'm proposing to not close because questions *neve*r need to demonstrate their *raison d'être*, nor need they ever be notable in any way. Many are not. Five up votes on the answer demonstrates readers found the information interesting and/or helpful, and considering it couldn't exist without the question being posted first, that demonstrates that the question was certainly worth asking. Hundreds if not a thousand questions here arguably fit the proposed criteria. This is a bad precedent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to several requests ([1](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33460/what-was-the-first-piece-of-wood-to-reach-the-far-side-of-the-moon-or-the-first/33929#comment103950_33460), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33460/what-was-the-first-piece-of-wood-to-reach-the-far-side-of-the-moon-or-the-first/33929#comment104585_33460)), I will answer my own question.

I have found the following...

Leonard David's INSIDE OUTER SPACE blogpost [Farside Science: The Saga of Ranger 4’s Moon Journey](http://www.leonarddavid.com/farside-science-the-saga-of-ranger-4s-moon-journey/)

> There’s an interesting historical side note given China’s imminent, milestone making robotic landing on the farside of the Moon.
>
> The U.S. Ranger spacecraft series was a set of kamikaze-like missions, hurled to the Moon to take photos of the lunar surface before a high-speed crash.
>
> NASA’s Block 2, Ranger 4 was launched on April 23, 1962, rocketed moonward via an Atlas Agena-B booster from Cape Canaveral Air Force Station, Florida. This craft carried a unique scientific experiment – a lightweight balsa wood impact limiter that encapsulated a transmitter and a seismometer designed by the Caltech Seismological Laboratory.
>
> [...]
>
> Difficult to spot
>
> It would be very difficult to identify any specific impact crater associated with Ranger 4 says noted Moon expert, Philip Stooke. He is Professor Emeritus and Adjunct Research Professor within the Department of Geography, and Center for Planetary Science and Exploration, at the University of Western Ontario.
>
> “The whole area has been imaged at high resolution by LRO so we probably have a picture of the crater,” Stooke told Inside Outer Space.
>
> Stooke points out one thing to consider.
>
> “What did people know about the farside at that time? Practically nothing! So, to calculate an impact location, you plot the trajectory, as well as you know it, and see where it intersects the lunar surface,” Stooke says. But if you know nothing at all about the topography, he continues, you have to use an approximation – it would have just been a sphere the mean size of the Moon. The actual point would vary a bit if there is a difference between the real topography and the assumed sphere.
>
> “**I don’t think anyone has ever gone back and recalculated the impact point for this or other missions like the NASA Lunar Orbiters using modern topography. If they did I think the orbiters could be found eventually, but I think the Ranger 4 location is probably still too uncertain to find it,” Stooke concludes**.

Wikipedia's [Ranger 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranger_4) states that it was the first spacecraft to reach the far side of the Moon, and carried the first wood to reach the far side as well:

> Ranger 4 was a spacecraft of the Ranger program designed to transmit pictures of the lunar surface to Earth stations during a period of 10 minutes of flight prior to crashing upon the Moon, to rough-land a seismometer capsule on the Moon, to collect gamma-ray data in flight, to study radar reflectivity of the lunar surface, and to continue testing of the Ranger program for development of lunar and interplanetary spacecraft. An onboard computer failure caused failure of the deployment of the solar panels and navigation systems; **as a result the spacecraft crashed on the far side of the Moon without returning any scientific data. It was the first spacecraft of the United States to reach another celestial body.**
>
> Ranger 4 was a Block II Ranger spacecraft virtually identical to Ranger 3. The basic vehicle was 331 kg (730 lb) 3.1 m (10 ft) high and consisted of **a lunar capsule covered with a balsawood impact-limiter, 650 mm (26 in) in diameter**, a mono-propellant mid-course motor, a 5080 lbf (22.6 kN) thrust retrorocket, and a gold- and chrome-plated hexagonal base 1.5 m in diameter.

Later...

> [...]Even though lunar impact would occur as planned, the mission was for all intents and purposes a failure. Making it a more bitter pill to swallow was the nearly-flawless launch vehicle performance. The booster problems that affected Rangers 1-3 had been resolved, only for the probe itself to completely fail, as unlike the previous missions, Ranger 4 did not return any useful data. Finding the cause of the timer malfunction could also be difficult since it had occurred during the coasting phase prior to trans-lunar injection when Ranger 4 was passing between tracking stations in the Caribbean and South Africa.
>
> Without solar power, Ranger 4's batteries ran down on the morning of April 26 and the radio transponder ceased operating. The tiny transmitter in the seismometer capsule continued sending out a 50-milliwatt signal. **Ranger 4 impacted the far side of the Moon (229.3 degrees E, 15.5 degrees S) at 9600 km/hr at 12:49:53 UT on April 26, 1962 after 64 hours of flight.
>
> NASA officials tried to put a positive spin on the mission, noting that it was the first time an American spacecraft had reached the surface of the Moon and that the probe was "far more sophisticated" than the Soviet Luna 2 space probe in 1959, which had been little more than a pressurized sphere designed to deposit pennants on the surface at impact. The excellent performance of the Atlas-Agena booster had also raised morale.
>
> This spacecraft, similar in design to Ranger 3, was the first American spacecraft to reach another celestial body. Although the spacecraft did not achieve its primary objective, the Atlas-Agena-Ranger combination performed without fault for the first time. **It acquired the dubious honor for being the first spacecraft to impact the far side of the Moon as well.**

See [@MarkAdler's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18862/12102) to the question*Puzzler - which spacecraft(s) incorporated real wooden structural elements?* for **much more interesting vintage photos!**

---

[image] [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1964_71394L.jpg)