# Is there an estimate for the average mass of all meteoroids and asteroids hitting Earth's atmosphere in one year?

Tags: asteroid, impact, mass, meteoroid

I wonder how much mass is entering Earth's atmosphere every year in the form of meteoroids and asteroids. This excludes micro-meteoroids, dust particles, molecules etc.

Quick search result talks only about the number of object:

> Every year, the Earth is hit by about 6100 meteors large enough to reach the ground, or about 17 every day, research has revealed.

[[source]](https://cosmosmagazine.com/space/earth-hit-by-17-meteors-a-day/)

Background: comparison of this natural reentry mass to the mass of reentering satellites, [What impact will the deorbiting of thousands of satellites have on the atmosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/46291/what-impact-will-the-deorbiting-of-thousands-of-satellites-have-on-the-atmospher)

Comment: Did you try to look up "meteorites flux"? You will have to specify a minimum mass for exclusion of objects you do not consider as dangerous to get a meaningful answer. Also, mass alone will not suffice for comparison. Satellites are made in materials that disintegrate easily in the atmosphere. Regardless, you will not have difficulty convincing, w/o requiring "scientific" arguments, that a plane is more likely to be hit by a meteorite than by a decaying satellite or man-made orbiting objects. The only differences is in liability.

Comment: NASA states 44 tonnes of [meteoritic material](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/asteroids-comets-and-meteors/meteors-and-meteorites/overview/?page=0&per_page=40&order=id+asc&search=&condition_1=meteor_shower%3Abody_type) falls on the Earth each day.

Comment: In Earth Science SE: [Is Earth getting heavier or lighter?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16688/6031) and various linked sources, and in Astronomy SE: [If 50 tons or more of debris falls to earth everyday, is Earth getting heavier?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/11823/7982)

Comment: We use 3 distinct terms here: meteorid, meteorite and meteor. The differences are given by [Britannica here](https://www.britannica.com/story/whats-the-difference-between-a-meteoroid-a-meteor-and-a-meteorite). The OP's source: 17 meteorites reach the ground per day. Fred's NASA source (my interpretation): the Earth (and its atmosphere) crosses a cloud of 44 metric tons of meteors/day. In other terms, the Earth captures 44t of meteorids/day. Otherwise, the numbers would not be coherent (17 meteorites landed for a total of 44T today !?).

Comment: @Fred thanks that's what I've been looking for